# Build a semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: semidirect-product

For $p$ prime and odd I'm trying to build a non trivial semidirect group  $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

So, for that, I look for the homomorphisms between  $Aut\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\right)$and $ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

$$Aut\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\right)=\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{*}=\left(\mathbb{Z}/p(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\right)= \left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)\times\left(\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\right)$$

The number of homorphism is the $\gcd(p\,,p\cdot(p-1))=p$. Then, we know there are $p-1$ non trivial homomorphism that induce a non trivial semidirect product.

My question is how can I build one of this semidirect group?

As all the elements in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)$ have order $p$. The homomorphism $\phi$ map $$1\mapsto(a,0)\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)\times\left(\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\right)$$

So  $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)$ act only in the first coordinate

Is that correct?

Comment: Well, inversion $\;x^c\mapsto x^{-1}\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\langle c\rangle=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ is always a good try in these cases...

Answer (score 2):

A nontrivial semidirect product will be $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z\rtimes_{\varphi}\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ for some nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\to{\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z)=U(p^2)$. The automorphisms of $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ are of the form $x\mapsto ax$ for residue classes $a$ represented by integers coprime to $p$. It suffices then to find an element of multiplicative order $p$ within $U(p^2)$ to send $1\in\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ to.

These elements are $1+kp$ for the integer values $k=1,\cdots,p-1$. A group presentation that works uniformly for the resulting semidirect products is $G_k:=\langle x,y:x^{p^2}=y^p=e,yxy^{-1}=x^{1+kp}\rangle$.

Let $\sigma\equiv(1+jp)/(1+kp)$ mod $p^2$. Then $x\mapsto x,y\mapsto y^{\sigma}$ induces an isomorphism $G_j\cong G_k$. Thus all of the nontrivial semidirect products are the same up to isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why the automorphism are of that form?

Comment: @MaríaCC Chronologically students should study cyclic groups (and their automorphisms) well before semidirect products. Perhaps it could be useful to freshen up or review. Let $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ be the cyclic group of order $n$. Any automorphism must send the generator $1$ to another generator, which must be represented by an integer coprime to $n$. The automorphism is determined by where it sends $1$. Conversely if $(r,n)=1$ then $1\mapsto r$ extends to an automorphism of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Thus the automorphisms are in bijection with the group of units. Check they have the same group structure.

Comment: Oh yes! It's true. Thank you.  I've studied cyclic groups before, but sometimes I lose concentration, above all after 12 hours of studying finitely groups :P

Comment: But, however I don't understand your explanation  since the second paragraph... sorry.